# auto balance or summing

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

I have a table for material consumption, same product with different cost and stock as per bellow

```
itcode  cost    stock
100       10    100
100       11    110
100       12    500
100       13    200
```

If I consume a quantity of 300 i need to get the result as follows

```
itcode  cost    stock   auto-deduct  balance_of_stock
100     10        100    100             0
100     11        110    110             0
100     12        500    90             410
```

the quantity has to deduct automatically from beginning

Comment: Do you mean auto-deduct and  balance_of_stock are columns in the table, or just result-set columns? (I.e. should those values be stored or just returned?)

Comment: What have you tried so far? Show us your current query and describe what's wrong with its result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have used a derived table to calculate accumulated stock (rsum). CASE's are when calculating auto_deduct and balance_of_stock.

```
select itcode,
       cost, 
       stock,
       case when rsum - 300 > 0 then stock + 300 - rsum
            else stock end as auto_deduct,
       case when rsum < 300 then 0
            else rsum - 300 end balance_of_stock
from
(select b1.*,
        (select sum(stock) from b b3
         where b3.itcode = b1.itcode
           and b3.cost <= b1.cost) as rsum
 from b b1
 where (select sum(stock) from b b2
        where b2.itcode = b1.itcode
          and b2.cost >= b1.cost) >= 300)
```